# incompatible types in assignment of ‘char’ to ‘char [100]’

Tags: c++, pointers

I am doing a review for school and I'm having a problem writing a function that creates a new struct and return a pointer to it.

```
// Review program

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
Book * makeBook(char * title, char * authorFName, char * authorLName, int numOfPages);

struct PersonName {
    char first[50];
    char last[50];
};
struct Book {
    char title[100];
    PersonName author;
    int numOfPages;
};

int main()
{
    char test[100] = "Hello, world";
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
Book * makeBook(char * title, char * authorFName, char * authorLName, int numOfPages)
{
    Book newBook;
    newBook.title = *title;

    Book* pBook = &newBook;
    return pBook;
}
```

The error, in the title, occurs because of `newBook.title = *title;`. Any help wpuld be appreciated.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to an automatic object going out of scope.  Such a pointer is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct, you cannot copy an array using the assignment operator.

Try `strcpy(newBook.title, title)`, or a variant with a maximum length.

`strcpy` is found in `<string.h>` or `<cstring>`.

Answer (score 0):

*title is of type char. You are trying to assign that to an array of char. Hence the error.

You cannot assign arrays with the assignment operator. You need to perform a copy. For instance:

```
strcpy(newbook.title, title);
```

It's rather hard to know why you are eschewing the C++ standard string container and using C constructs for your strings.

There are more problems with your code. Not the least of which is where you return the address of a local variable out of the function. De-referencing that pointer invokes undefined behaviour and no good can come of that. A dynamic allocation is needed as things stand.

Your parameters should be const char* rather than char*. Using the latter makes it inconvenient to pass constand strings to your function.

Comment: "for school" is probably all the explanation needed concerning use of `char*`.

Comment: @Ben Probably. School is doing it all wrong. Writing C and compiling as C++ seems like a terrible state of affairs.

Comment: I don't know, C-style strings provide a really intuitive understanding of basic heap memory concepts, i feel

Comment: Knowing how strings are actually stored and manipulated is important too.

Comment: @Ben So teach C. Still an important language. At the very list make the distinction between these two different languages. So that we don't have armies of newly minted graduates who cannot tell them apart.

Comment: Also, your latest comment about undefined behavior is a bit premature.  Forming the pointer is perfectly valid, and returning it, although a terrible idea, is still well-formed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A C++ compiler is still much better for teaching low-level programming skills.  Why should anyone have to mess with declarations before use, or implicit int, or the mangled mess that are C function prototypes?  You can call it something other than "Introductory C++", but then, the course probably isn't called that to begin with.

Comment: For certain, the course that is a prerequisite for microcontrollers / embedded systems needs to teach these low-level topics.  And taking away the type safety provided by C++ just because "it isn't modern C++ style for large desktop applications" does no one any favors.  This is how you do embedded code.  C++ type safety is superior.  So use it.  And name the course to match what is being taught, not the language used to convey those concepts.

Comment: @Ben Nobody says you have to use a C89 compiler. You can use a modern C compiler that addresses much of that. And even without that you can just write clean code and not rely on implicit int. This doesn't look very like a low level course to me. Looks like a bad introduction to application programming.

Comment: Modern C compilers still have terrible type safety compared to C++.  Empty parentheses in prototypes disable type checking.  C-style casts still are unclear and a hazard to maintenance.  etc, etc.  There's only one reason I know of to use C, and that's if your target has no C++ compiler.  And that's a very rare case any more.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure why you had to take it out on me. Not really appreciated.

Comment: Because your first comment required a response, lest a student take it as the consensus of experts.  BTW, if what you meant was that "This is a poor way to approach teaching application development; where resources are not scarce modern C++ abstractions should be preferred." I would agree.  But that isn't what you said.  You said a C compiler should be preferred to a C++ compiler when teaching low-level concepts, which has no basis in reality that I've ever seen.

Comment: @Ben It seemed fairly clear that this is teaching app development from the types in the Q.

Comment: @Ben Why is what you advocate so seldom done? Why do people continue using C? Why teach a style of programming that is seldom applied?

Comment: "Seldom applied"?  There are huge numbers of embedded devices programmed with C++.  Plenty of articles out there concerning which C++ features have low runtime costs and are therefore suitable in small embedded systems.  Plenty of work on C++ compilers for such systems.  Most C developers I know who aren't moving to C++ (where the tools are available) are the same ones who won't move from C89 to C99 -- who put in minimal effort and don't want anything new because understanding it might require effort.  And managers who run projects at payscales that don't attract more competent developers.